# address sanitizer (-fsanitize=address) works with tcmalloc?

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer, tcmalloc

I would like to know -fsanitize=address option of gcc works with tcmalloc? or do we need to run by disabling tcmalloc? Or is it will be good if sanitizer is run enabling tcmalloc?

Comment: I think both asan and tcmalloc want to replace the global malloc with their own version. What exactly are you hoping to achieve by mixing both?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I guess OP wants to avoid rewriting makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developers usually discourage from combining ASan with non-Glibc allocators (e.g. [here](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/issues/810)) but theoretically there shouldn't be much difference - ASan is capable of intercepting any memory allocator on Linux (via symbol interposition).

Comment: Actually i am getting exact same dump as posted in the link you shared in comment above. Not sure what to do further

Comment: @Nasir Frankly I'd expect tcmalloc developers to fix this issue but worst case you can simply disable tcmalloc in sanitized build (it's a standard practice to have small changes in checked builds to e.g. work around known limitations in checkers).

Comment: @Nasir One option is [reporting](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/) this to Asan developers. You'd better [symbolize](http://tsdgeos.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/asan-and-gcc-how-to-get-line-numbers-in.html) the stacktrace before reporting so that they can see what's going on.